# Windows 8.1 Tablet USB Booting Android Install

Tags: android, windows

I have a [Linx7 tablet](http://www.linx-tablets.com/linx-7.html) with Windows 8.1 and I like to install Android Lollipop. I've done this in the past and it loads the USB connected and the setup will continue but in this case it's not the same. I cannot boot the device from the USB. I tried the following so far:

```
PC Setting > Update and Recovery > Recovery > Advance Start-up > Use a device 

PC Setting > Update and Recovery > Recovery > Advance Start-up > Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI firmware settings
```

I also tried changing the order of the boot in BIOS made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work by pressing F7 on startup. make sure you have connected keyboard prior to trying this.
JTS